# Independent Probabilities for Multiple Events

Tags: probability-theory

I don't understand my professor's definition of multiple independent events. [image: HisDefinition]

Does he mean that for $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots, A_n$ events to be independent that each $n$-tuplet (for $n = 2$ to $n$) must all be independent?

e.g., If 4 events (call them $A,B,C,D$) are independent then the number of equations that must be satisfied are: 
      $4 \choose 2$ pairs, $4 \choose 3$ trios, and the equation $P(A\wedge B\wedge C\wedge D)=P(A)P(B)P(C)P(D)$

Comment: Yes, he means that.

Comment: So if one equation isn't true, then the events are not independent?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P(A)=P(B)=1/2$ and $P(A\cap B)=1/4$, so these are independent events.

Let $C$ be false if $A$ and $B$ are both false or both true; and let $C$ be true otherwise.

Then obviously $C$ cannot be considered "independent" of $A$ and $B$ in any reasonable sense of the word.

But $P(A)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A)P(C)=P(A\cap C)$ and $P(B)P(C)=P(B\cap C)$.

And $P(A)P(B)P(C)=\dfrac18\ne0=P(A\cap B\cap C)$.

Comment: I have some trouble following your point. What do you mean when you said that C can't be considered 'independent'? That the truth of C depends on the truth of either A or B (or both)? Isn't that always the case for binary operators? 

Also, if $P(A)=P(B)=1/2$, then $P(C) = 0$ and $P(A)P(B)P(C)=0$

Comment: We have $\left.\begin{cases} \Pr(A\ \&\ B\ \&\ \text{not }C) & = 1/4, \\ \Pr(A\ \&\ \text{not B}\ \&\ C) & = 1/4, \\  \Pr(\text{not }A\ \&\ B\ \& C) & = 1/4, \\ \Pr(\text{not }A\ \&\ \text{not }B\ \&\ \text{not }C) & = 1/4. \end{cases}\right\}$.  So $\Pr(C)=1/2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, I meant that they are not independent since the truth of $C$ depends on that of $A$ and $B$ (and is completely determined by those), or the truth of $B$ depends on that of $A$ and $C$ (and is completely determined by those), or the truth of $A$ depends on that of $B$ and $C$ (and is completely determined by those). It is not true that $\Pr(C)=0$.  Perhaps you meant $\Pr(C\mid A\ \&\ B)=0$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Of course one can also say that $C$ is dependent on $A$ and $B$ in the sense that $0=\Pr(C\mid A\ \&\ B)\ne\Pr(C)=1/2$, and $1=\Pr(C\mid A\ \&\ \text{not }B)\ne\Pr(C)=1/2$, etc. ${}\qquad{}$