# if $P(A \cap B \cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$, does it necessarily means $A,B,C$ are independants?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Lets say we have the events $A,B,C$. We know that if they are independants, then the following occurs:
$$P(A \cap B \cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$$
But does it work the opposite way? If some $A,B,C$ events satisfies the equation above, does it mean they are necessarily independent?

Another question: when we say that $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ are independants, does it mean they are independants in pairs or in any $2 \le k \le n$ groups?

Comment: What if $A$ is a probability zero event?  What can you say about $B$ and $C$?

Comment: hmm nothing. $A \cap B = \emptyset$. same for $A \cap C$. It's doesn't tell nothing about the relation between $B$ and $C$

Comment: @BurakKaraosmanoğlu Links to brilliant.org are not very helpful because  one has to login

Comment: @ryden what means independent? Pairwise independent? Mutually independent? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_events

Comment: @miracle173 My mistake! I actually wanted to link another site. I deleted my first comment with your warning. Thanks! New comment in response to the question: You need to impose three extra mutual independence conditions for the independence of three events, independence of *A* and *B*, independence of *A* and *C*, and independence of *B* and *C*, as stated [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_1_independence.php). You may also refer [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081962/independent-probabilities-for-multiple-events?rq=1).

Comment: Two orthographic details: independants $\to$ independent : 1) no plural with an "s" for adjectives in english,  2) "a" should be "e"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A_1,...,A_n$ are independent when they are $k$-wise independent for all $2\le k \le n$. That is,  $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are independent if and only if for any subset of $k$ events with indices $i(1),\dots,i(k)$, you have
$$
P(A_{i(1)}\cap \dots \cap A_{i(k)})=P(A_{i(1)})\cdots P(A_{i(k)})
$$

Your question then boils down to whether $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$ implies $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, $P(A\cap C)=P(A)P(C)$ and $P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C)$.

A counterexample is $P(A\cap B \cap C)=1/8$, $P(A\cap B)=1/8$, $P(A\cap C)=3/8$, $P(B\cap C)=1/4$, $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=1/2$.

Additional:
To answer miracle173's question, consider the set $\{0,...,7\}$ and the subsets $A=\{0,...,3\}$, $B=\{0,1,4,5\}$, and $C=\{0,2,4,6\}$. We then take $P(i)=1/8,0,1/4,1/8,1/8,1/4,0,1/8$ for $i=0,...,7$. Since these numbers sum to one, we get a valid probability measure.

Comment: so, "independent" only means they are pairwise independent?

Comment: You can define other kinds of 'independence' as you like, but as far as I know pairwise independence is the only useful one. Wikipedia does define something other than pairwise independence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_events

Comment: alright, now i get it. thank you very much!

Comment: A counterexample consists of the sets A,B,C and not of some numbers for the probabilities. Maybe there do not exist sets that result in such probabilities.

Comment: Well, a counterexample is both the probability space (the sets) and the probability measure (the numbers). These numbers do in fact come from a measure on a valid sigma algebra/probability space.

Comment: For concreteness if you like, consider three coin tosses, let A, B, C be the event that the first, second, third land heads respectively, though these are rather strange coins!

Comment: How can I see that these numbers come from a measure on a valid sigma algebra?

Comment: Joshua, your answer is wrong and VERY misleading! Independence is NOT the same as pairwise independence! Independence of $A_1,\dots,A_n$ means that for any subset of variables $A_{i(1)},\dots,A_{i(k)}$, you have $P(A_{i(1)}\cap \dots \cap A_{i(k)})=P(A_{i(1)})\cdots P(A_{i(k)})$, pairwise means that only holds for $k=2$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_events. PLEASE either amend or delete your answer!

Comment: OK, your answer was mostly correct, and I fixed the incorrect comment at the beginning. Re: your first comment, mutual independence is more useful than pairwise independence.